# How can an @supports rule support name of animations in this statement?

Tags: html, css, w3c, feature-detection

I found this CSS on a page in the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing) and I don't know how it makes any sense, specifically the animation name part:

```css
@supports ((transition-property: color) or
           (animation-name: foo)) and
          (transform: rotate(10deg)) {
  // ...
}
```

I understand this supports rule:

```css
@supports (display: grid) {
  .main {
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

It means: if the browser supports the "grid" display type, then apply this rule. But what I don't understand is when the first example says `animation-name: foo`.

To me, that means: if the browser supports an animation with the name "foo", then apply this rule. I thought *you* (the developer) defined animations. Is it just a bad example?

Here is the documentation on [animation-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name). You define the animation name when you define a keyframe. So is it just saying: "Enable this query when someone has defined a keyframe rule with the name foo"? That would mean not whether there's "support" for an animation named "foo", but rather whether there exists an animation named "foo".

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing

Comment: if the browser support transform:rotate(10deg) AND support either transition-property or animation-name --> do what is inside

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/how-supports-works/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That means if the browser supports an animation with the name "foo" apply this rule. I thought you the developer defined animations. Is it just a bad example?

That's not really what it means. The difference between `display` and `animation-name` is that the first one takes a value in a set of predefined values, whereas the second one takes any valid string.

In [the CSS specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties), you can find the exhaustive list of values allowed for `display`. You are obliged to use a valid value, which is logical, and the support for different values isn't the same.

`animation-name` takes a value called `<keyframes-name>` and from [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#keyframes) we have:

```
<keyframes-name> = <custom-ident> | <string>
```

and

> Some properties accept arbitrary author-defined identifiers as a component value. This generic data type is denoted by `<custom-ident>`, and represents any valid CSS identifier that would not be misinterpreted as a pre-defined keyword in ... <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#identifier-value)</sup>
>
> Strings are denoted by  and consist of a sequence of characters delimited by double quotes or single quotes. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#string-value)</sup>

The property can take an infinite number of values and you are obliged to use a valid one, so any string will do the job (like `foo`). Since there is no support based on the value used, all of them will have equal support; that's why using a random string is OK to test the support of `animation-name`.

The logic is the same for al; you have to use a valid value, and then we test the support of this value. For `display`, you are restricted to some values and each one has different support between browsers. For `animation-name`, you have no restriction on the value and all of them have the same support.

If you try to use an invalid value for `animation-name`, it won't work:

```css
@supports (animation-name: a b ) {
  body {
    background:red;
  }
}
```

same as using an invalid value for display:

```css
@supports (display: 0 ) {
  body {
    background:red;
  }
}
```

---

The same logic applies to `transition-property`; that can take a `<custom-indent>` as value.

---

if you use a valid value for `animation-name` (even if the animation doesn't exist) and a valid value for `transition-property` (even if the property doesn't exist), then it will apply:

```css
@supports ((animation-name: myanimation) and (transition-property:a-random-name)) {
  body {
    background:green;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! The `custom-ident` confused me. I read it as `indent`. My suggestion is they say `id` or `identity`?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts well, engish isn't my best so I cannot say if your suggestion is better but I agree it's a bit confusing. If you check the specification, you will also find more keywords and more confusion (`identifier`,`indent`, `indent-token`,etc)

Comment: Yes. It's a small thing. The documentation has many authors so it's expected.

Comment: Interesting... In the last example (I added) it looks like *any* identifier is working whether foo exists or not (so red is shown). If you use `a b` it does not support that (and green is shown). So it's not actually checking if keyframe with name exists but possibly checking if syntax is correct. Can you confirm?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts yes exactly, that's what I am explaining :) you simply need a valid syntax and all the value have the same support. There is no support per value like for display.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I have updated the last example to show that we don't even need the keyframes, only a valid name for a potential keyframe